# Vba code to freeze panes columnwise

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone please suggest the syntax for freezing panes columns wise in excel VBA. I mean I have from column A to Z. I want to freeze columns A to D so that i can scroll columns E to Z freely . I tried some code in internet but no luck.

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried to record a macro?

Comment: Easiest this to do to find this sort of stuff out is to record a macro, and then do what you need manually. Then you can inspect the generated macro code and go from there.

Comment: Sorry..Am not a expert in excel actually

Comment: read this: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/macro-recorder.html

Answer (score 6):

normally I'd say that this would be the job of a paid consultant.. this one took all of 2 mins and 1 google search so here:

```
Sub Macro()


    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 4
        .SplitRow = 0
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```

That will use Excels "Freeze Panes" feature to freeze columns a - d. keep in mind, that just means that columns a - d will always be visible, this does not affect rows, so when scrolling down all rows will scroll together.

Please keep in mind that stackoverflow is for programing "help" and in most cases people will not code macros for you, they will help you when you are stuck in a macro. I just recorded this macro and changed one thing.